# Summing across columns after pivot table

Tags: python-3.x, sum, pivot-table, multi-index

I created a pivot table using pd.pivot_table, with 2 different column header layers. How can I sum across these columns by selectively filtering for a column?

Pivot table:

```
      sum       count

   A | B | C | A | B | C

1  2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4

2  2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4

3  2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4

4  2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4
```

Desired output:

```
      sum       count    sum of sum  sum of count

   A | B | C | A | B | C

1  2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4  |   6    |  10

2  2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4  |   6    |  10

3  2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4  |   6    |  10

4  2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4  |   6    |  10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, it is rough answer but I am sure it will help to solve your problem

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                         "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                  "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
                         "one", "one", "two", "two"],
                  "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small",
                         "small", "large", "small", "small",
                          "large"],
                  "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                  "E": [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]})


table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'],
                    columns=['C'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)

table2 =  table.T      #This created table like you

#creating new table with sum of level 0
table3 = table2.groupby(level=0,axis = 1).sum().rename(columns = {'bar':'sum_bar','foo':'sum_foo'})

#concatenate table 2 and 3 to get final result,
result = pd.concat([table2, table3], axis=1, sort=False)
```

### Output:

```
table2
Out[35]: 
A     bar     foo    
B     one two one two
C                    
large   4   7   4   0
small   5   6   1   6

result
Out[36]: 
       (bar, one)  (bar, two)  (foo, one)  (foo, two)  sum_bar  sum_foo
C                                                                      
large           4           7           4           0       11        4
small           5           6           1           6       11        7
```